# Xvfb not found on your system

Tags: xvfb

I try to use Xvfb to make the headless code run. However, I encountered the problem that "Xvfb not found on your system" when I tried to run my ruby code. Then I tried to install Xvfb using

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

However, "apt-get: command not found" is showed. Thus, I have not idea what should be installed to avoid the original Xvfb error. Any helps? Thank you.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install xvfb` helped me in this case. You should investigate why you can't access apt-get.

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but found it will trying to find the apt-get commands. The command not found is likely because you are not on a debian system. So you should probably be using yum.

Some potentially useful links:
https://serverfault.com/questions/344793/install-xvfb-via-yum-yum-repository-for-xvfb
[How to install Xvfb (X virtual framebuffer) on Redhat 6.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671552/how-to-install-xvfb-x-virtual-framebuffer-on-redhat-6-5)

Answer (score 3):

In CentOS 7, the following command will install it:

```
$ sudo yum install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb
```