# How to install Xvfb (X virtual framebuffer) on Redhat 6.5?

Tags: linux, installation, redhat

I have tried to install the Xvfb on red-hat 6.5 using

```
yum -y install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb
```

but it is not installed and it is giving msg that

```
No package xorg-x11-server-Xvfb available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Plese help me to install Xvfb on Redhat 6.5 to remove the headless exception in the Applet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

The `xorg-x11-server-Xvfb` package is officially available from RedHat for RHEL 6 and RHEL 7 under the **Optional** channel (RHEL Workstation Optional, or RHEL Server Optional).

From the comments: To enable the optional repo: `subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-7-server-optional-rpms` and then you can install the package with `yum install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb`

Comment: To enable the optional repo:  `subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-7-server-optional-rpms` and `yum install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb`  (this is for rhel7, season to taste).

Comment: If you are running this inside docker image you cannot enable the repos cauz by default it is disable.

Answer (score 14):

I was able to download the RPM and then install it locally after reading this [article](https://github.com/capensis/canopsis/wiki/Install-from-packages)

```
 wget http://vault.centos.org/6.2/os/x86_64/Packages/xorg-x11-server-Xvfb-1.10.4-6.el6.x86_64.rpm
 yum localinstall xorg-x11-server-Xvfb-1.10.4-6.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: This answer is way better, because it does not depend on owning a subscription.

Comment: The link to the article is broken.