# Need to run protractor tests with chrome using xvfb in RHEL 7.xx box

Tags: google-chrome, protractor, rhel, headless, xvfb

I need to run protractor tests with chrome on a headless mode in a remote RHEL 7.xx box. I realize that I need to have xvfb installed on the remote RHEl box and run using xvfb.

Can somebody help me with this installation/configuration if something has really worked for someone.

Comment: hope this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39080917/how-to-run-protractor-testcases-in-jenkin-with-a-headless-browser#answer-39081155

Comment: I think you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671552/how-to-install-xvfb-x-virtual-framebuffer-on-redhat-6-5 - you need to enable the optional repo