# How to install Xvfb on RH8?

Tags: redhat, yum, xvfb

I need to install Xvfb on Redhat 8, however the usual way doesn't work:

`yum -y install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb`

> No match for argument: xorg-x11-server-Xvfb
>
> Error: Unable to find a match: xorg-x11-server-Xvfb

From here [How to install Xvfb (X virtual framebuffer) on Redhat 6.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671552/how-to-install-xvfb-x-virtual-framebuffer-on-redhat-6-5) I tried the suggestion:

```
wget http://vault.centos.org/6.2/os/x86_64/Packages/xorg-x11-server-Xvfb-1.10.4-6.el6.x86_64.rpm
yum localinstall xorg-x11-server-Xvfb-1.10.4-6.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

But that gives:

> Error:
> Problem: conflicting requests
>
> - nothing provides libXdmcp.so.6()(64bit) needed by xorg-x11-server-Xvfb-1.10.4-6.el6.x86_64
> - nothing provides libXfont.so.1()(64bit) needed by xorg-x11-server-Xvfb-1.10.4-6.el6.x86_64
> - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) needed by xorg-x11-server-Xvfb-1.10.4-6.el6.x86_64
> - nothing provides xorg-x11-server-common >= 1.10.4-6.el6 needed by xorg-x11-server-Xvfb-1.10.4-6.el6.x86_64

Is there any way to install Xvfb on RH8?

Comment: Try adding  install epel and then trying.

Comment: No, epel doesn't have it either. I will add an answer with the unfortunate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this (without an RHEL subscription) is to do the following installs which work only when in this order:

```
yum install -y libXScrnSaver \
mesa-libgbm nss at-spi2-atk libX11-xcb \
ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/rhel/rhel-8-beta/appstream/x86_64/Packages/libxkbfile-1.0.9-9.el8.x86_64.rpm \
ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/rhel/rhel-8-beta/appstream/x86_64/Packages/xorg-x11-xkb-utils-7.7-26.el8.x86_64.rpm \
ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/rhel/rhel-8-beta/appstream/x86_64/Packages/xorg-x11-server-common-1.20.2-5.el8.x86_64.rpm \
ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/rhel/rhel-8-beta/appstream/x86_64/Packages/xorg-x11-xauth-1.0.9-12.el8.x86_64.rpm \
ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/rhel/rhel-8-beta/appstream/x86_64/Packages/libXdmcp-1.1.2-11.el8.x86_64.rpm \
ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/rhel/rhel-8-beta/appstream/x86_64/Packages/libXfont2-2.0.3-2.el8.x86_64.rpm \
ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/rhel/rhel-8-beta/appstream/x86_64/Packages/xorg-x11-server-Xvfb-1.20.2-5.el8.x86_64.rpm;
```

I don't know why it's so difficult.

Comment: it says This command has to be run with superuser privileges (under the root user on most systems). did you have any other way of doing it @automaton

Answer (score 3):

Create the file /etc/yum.repos.d/centos8.repo

```
[CentOS-8]
name=CentOS-8
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8-stream/AppStream/x86_64/os/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://www.centos.org/keys/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Official
```

Then:

```
rpm --import https://www.centos.org/keys/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Official
dnf install -y xorg-x11-server-Xvfb
```

If you are trying to run something like cypress headless, you might also need some of these:

```
atk java-atk-wrapper at-spi2-atk gtk3 libXt mesa-libgbm libdrm
```

Comment: it says This command has to be run with superuser privileges (under the root user on most systems). you have any other way around, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The following docker file fixed it for us using UBI 8 openjdk.

We added the CentOS repository and enabled it.

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/openjdk-8

USER 0

RUN adduser --system non-root

ARG CERTIFICATES_DIR

# Copy root CA certs
COPY ${CERTIFICATES_DIR}/AAAAAAAAAAAA.crt /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
COPY ${CERTIFICATES_DIR}/BBBBBBBBBBBB.crt /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
COPY ${CERTIFICATES_DIR}/CCCCCCCCCCCCC.crt /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/

# Install CA certs
RUN update-ca-trust

RUN mkdir /app && chmod g+rwx /app

ARG APPLICATION_CLASS
ENV APPLICATION_CLASS=${APPLICATION_CLASS}

ARG DEPENDENCY_DIR

COPY ${DEPENDENCY_DIR}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY ${DEPENDENCY_DIR}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY ${DEPENDENCY_DIR}/BOOT-INF/classes /app


RUN chmod -R g+rwx /app/*

RUN printf '[CentOS-8]\nname=CentOS-8\nbaseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8-stream/AppStream/x86_64/os/\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=1\ngpgkey=https://www.centos.org/keys/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Official' >> /etc/yum.repos.d/ubi.repo

RUN microdnf -y update && \
    microdnf -y install freetype fontconfig dejavu-sans-mono-fonts dejavu-serif-fonts dejavu-sans-fonts xorg-x11-server-Xvfb && microdnf clean all


RUN fc-cache --really-force --verbose


RUN mkdir /tmp/.X11-unix \
    && chmod 1777 /tmp/.X11-unix \
    && chown root:root /tmp/.X11-unix/

ENV LANG "en_US.UTF-8"
ENV LC_ALL "en_US.ISO8859-1"
ENV TZ "Europe/Stockholm"
ENV DISPLAY ":99"


USER non-root

EXPOSE 8080 8443

WORKDIR /

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "java -cp app:app/lib/* ${PISA_JAVA_OPTS} ${JAVA_OPTIONS} ${APPLICATION_CLASS} & \
                         Xvfb ${DISPLAY} >> /app/kola/xvfb.log 2>&1"]
```